# Como fazer um Exit Popup com jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Estou começando agora a usar jquery agora, gostaria de saber com eu faço para aparecer uma imagem assim que mouse vai para fora da tela, de maneira simples, mas no intuito de aprender a fazer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ideia é fazer um elemento ser exibido quando se tira o mouse da tela.

Uma das formas seria fazer uma div com uns 5px de altura e deixar fixa no topo da página; quando o mouse passar por ela, exibir o pop-up de saída.

Mas achei mais interessante usar recursos como esse abaixo, que não serviu para o meu caso porque ele continua sendo executado outras vezes.

```
$(window).on('mouseout', function() {
   $('#popup').show();
})
```

Tem também esse modo abaixo, mas não recomendo porque ele fica observando o mouse se mover e não parece muito performático.

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    if(e.pageY <= 5)
        {
            $('#exitpopup').fadeIn();
        }
})
```

No fim, o que funcionou foi

```
var $window = $(window),
    $html = $('html');    
    $window.on('mouseleave', function(event) {
        if (!$html.is(event.target))
            return;
            $('#exitPopUp').show();
    });
```

Não esqueça de colocar o botão de saída. Algumas versões criam duas divs, uma de fundo e uma do conteúdo, para que seja possível clicar na do fundo e sair da pop-up.

```
$("#exitButton").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    $("#exitpopup").hide();
});
```

Também existem exemplos que esperam um tempo da pessoa na página antes de exibir o pop-up. Para isso, basta usar

```
setTimeout(function(){ [FUNÇÃO] },3000);
```

E ainda alguns exemplos usam cookies, mas como estamos falando de server-side, prefiro usar Local Storage mesmo que não funcione em navegadores antigos.

```
// Criando a data e somando 6 dias
var someDate = new Date();
var numberOfDaysToAdd = 6;
someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd); 

// Guardar
localStorage.setItem("popupTime", someDate);
// Usar
localStorage.getItem("popupTime");
```

Você pode ver as suas variáveis no localstorage no inspecionar elementos do chrome

[image: Local storage]

Finalmente, o script todo ficou assim:

```
// Fechar pop-up
$(".closePopUp").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    $("#exitPopUp").hide();
});

// mostrar pop-up
var showpopup = function(){
    // Mostrar só depois da pessoa estar na página por 5 segundos
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        // e a pessoa sair da página
        var $window = $(window),
            $html = $('html');
        $window.on('mouseleave', function(event) {
            if (!$html.is(event.target))
                return;
            $('#exitPopUp').show();
        });                
    },5000);        
}


// exibir depois de quantos dias?
var numberOfDaysToAdd = 6;

// que dia é hoje?
var today = new Date().getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)

var future = new Date().getTime() + (30+numberOfDaysToAdd)*24*60*60*1000;

// verifica se existe alguma data guardada
var showedTime = localStorage.getItem("popupTime");


// se sim
if(showedTime !== null){

    // verifica se já passou tempo suficiente desde a última exibição
    showedTime = parseInt(showedTime);
    if (today > showedTime){
        // Mostrar pop-up
        showpopup();
        // Atualizar data no localstorage
        localStorage.setItem("popupTime", future);          
    }
} else {
    // a pop-up nunca foi mostrada antes, então vamos criar a data 
    localStorage.setItem("popupTime", future);

    // Mostrar pop-up
    showpopup();
}
```

Fontes:

- http://tonylea.com/go/examples/jquery-exit-popup/
- https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/480719/jquery-exit-popup-script
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873508/how-can-i-check-if-the-mouse-exited-the-browser-window-using-javascript-jquery